# How to open a .aes256 file

Tags: files

So I downloaded something from the internet that I barely know what it is the most info I have is from the name(2016-11-07_WL-Insurance_US.aes256). I don't know how to open this file and would like some help. Any software recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

This is an encrypted file distributed by Wikileaks. You can't open it without decryption key only known to a few people in Wikileaks. The decryption key will not be released unless something serious happens to e.g. Julian Assange (that's why file is called insurance).